# Using "or" in a python for loop to define default sequence

Tags: python, for-loop

I have seen somewhere this usage of a for loop:

```
def func(seq=None):
    for i in seq or [1, 2, 3]:
       print i

func([3, 4, 5])  # Will print 3, 4, 5
func()           # Will print 1, 2, 3
```

It seems that when using or/and when using the "in" keyword it will select the first/last "usable" sequence in order to run the for loop.

I have not seen any official documentation and was wondering how it works and if it's commonly used.

Comment: `seq or [1, 2, 3]` is roughly equivalent to `seq if len(seq) > 0 else [1, 2, 3]`, i.e. providing a default in case it gets an empty sequence. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's more like `seq if bool(seq) else [1,2,3]`, with the empty list being `False`!

Comment: @KarlBarker that's more accurate but probably less helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of `or` (or `and` ) operator, when you do -

```
a or b
```

It returns `a` if a is not a false-like value, otherwise it returns `b` . `None` (and empty lists) are false like value.

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) -

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> (Note that neither and nor or restrict the value and type they return to False and True, but rather return the last evaluated argument. This is sometimes useful, e.g., if `s` is a string that should be replaced by a default value if it is empty, the expression `s or 'foo'` yields the desired value. Because not has to invent a value anyway, it does not bother to return a value of the same type as its argument, so e.g., not 'foo' yields False, not ''.)

---

Also, in case of `for` loop, `in` is actually part of the `for` loop construct, its not an operator. Documentation for `for` loop construct [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for).

---

Hence when you do -

```
for i in seq or [1, 2, 3]:
```

It would first evaluate -

```
seq or [1 , 2, 3]
```

And returns the `seq` list if its not none or empty, so that you can iterate over that. Otherwise, it would return [1, 2, 3] and you would iterate over that.

Answer (score 0):

No! It's the operator priority! `or` before `in`…
[Precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=precedence#operator-precedence), §6.15.
So `seq or [1, 2, 3]` is evaluated before entering the loop. And seq is `None`.

Comment: Why this -1? I don't understand!

Comment: `in` is not an operator in that context.

Comment: Well… Look at Python official doc `https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=precedence#operator-precedence` 6.15. `seq or [1, 2, 3]` is evaluated before entering in the loop.

Comment: @Clodion You are new to stackoverflow so you will have many -1.

Comment: @mohan3d: Yes, may be! :-). But when I'm on the right way, whatever the reputation, I can show this is the truth (if I'm right!) ;-)

Comment: @Clodion No, thats not the reason, when `in` is used in for loop, its not the `in` operator, its a part of the for loop construct. Check my answer.